# Possible feedback from the first phone interview

Tags: interviewing, job-search

Yesterday, I had a technical phone interview from a company that I've applied for. At the end, they asked me if I have further questions regarding to job or the company. I asked them the next steps of the recruitment process in case of a positive response from their side. The answer from them was the following:

Will you be available in the next two weeks? or even next week? Our second step of the recruitment process is another face-to-face interview in our premises, etc...

Can someone explain if this is a possible step for the next process? Is this a positive or a neutral sign from their side?

Comment: I suggest you contact them and ask.  Their response is clear.  If they choose to go forward with you, then you will get a in-person interview, if they decided not to go forward with you then won't get that interview.

Answer (score 3):

Their response is neutral and common because they have nothing to hide. Some places are so clueless about the hiring process (because they don't have one) they may not be able to answer the question with this much detail.

I think it is in your favor that you asked. It shows you're interested. It is rare for anyone to ask you the hypothetical question, "If we made you an offer at this time, would you accept?" Volunteering your interest in the position is always a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain if this is a possible step for the next process?
>   Is this a positive or a neutral sign from their side?

Yes, of course this is a possible next step.

At this point it's very slightly positive. They are asking if you would be available in case they decide to continue on to the next step.

They haven't yet scheduled step 2, so nothing is definite.

On the other hand you weren't ruled out during the phone interview, or they wouldn't have asked your availability. That's a mildly positive sign.